# backbone model is not structured properly

Tags: jquery, spring, backbone.js

I have a backbone model like follows

```
app.Collection.BrandCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model: app.Model.Brand
});

app.Model.Brand = Backbone.Model.extend({
       url: function(){
          return '/brand/edit/save';
       }
});
```

I am retrieving my collection

```
var brandcollection = new app.Collection.BrandCollection();
      brandcollection.url = '/brands';
      brandcollection.fetch({
          success: function(collection, response, options) { 
               app.views.brandline = new app.View.BrandPanelView({
                  model: brandcollection
               });
               $('#tab-content').empty();
               $('#tab-content').append(app.views.brandline.render());
        }
      });
```

my controller

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/brands", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public Collection<BrandDTO> listBrands(
```

using firebug i discovered that the attributes are under special name `brandDTOList`. that why i can't get the BrandDTO attributes when i do model.toJson().I have no clue whats the reason.?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you might need a custom parse on app.Collection.BrandCollection

something like

```
parse: function(response){
    return response.brandDTOList;
}
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

Comment: I know this will work out but I have 2 exactly same situations. Same return type. One is returning Object directly and another is returning List inside object...Wierd